# Function Return Value

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript script that needs to figure out a date based on two params: a date a user types in, which is passed into the 'date' param, and the number of days it should be out from the first param.

The function works well until the return statement.  The return statement returns 'null'  I am struggling in figuring out what I am doing wrong in my syntax to return the updated date value.  Help please.

```
function calcDate(date, holdDays){

        var expirationDate = null;
        var validDate = noWeekendsOrHolidays(date); //jqueryui datepicker

        if(holdDays != 0){
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

            if(validDate[0] == true){
                calcDate(date, holdDays - 1)
            } else {
                calcDate(date, holdDays)
            }

        } else{
            expirationDate = moment(date);
            return expirationDate;
        }
        return expirationDate;
    }

var expirationDate = calcDate("3/7/2016",3) //expect 3/10/2016
```

Comment: FYI, I have also tried replacing the first return inside of the else block to return true; and return false;

Again, just not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: `expirationDate` is only set if the last `else` statement is reached, which only happens if `holdDays === 0`.

Comment: Instead of adding complexity with moment.js, why not just pass an actual date into calcDate()? As in, `calcDate(new Date(2016, 03, 07), 3);`

Comment: I admit, I'm a little confused by your code. It seems like you are just trying find the date that is `x` number of days after a given date. Is this what you are trying to accomplish? Because your code is way too complex for that.

Comment: You are not using the return values of your recursive function calls to `calcDate`

Comment: So a few clarification points from these comments - 1) yes, the expirationDate should only be set in the else because it is a recursive function call.  2) This function is actually used with jqueryui DatePicker.  The moment.js is used for formatting.  I can use elsewhere as it is not really critical in this function itself.  3) Yes, I realize it can be cleaned up with something like moment.js and add(3,"d"), but the fn is used to skip weekends/holidays.  Basically, it should only count business days, so something simple like .add will not work.

Comment: @forgivenson notice in the recursive call I am decrementing the holdDays.

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved with by setting the variable value at the beginning of the code block and changing the if statement (@forgivenson, put some thought in after reading your comment above).

```
function calcDate(date, holdDays){
    var expirationDate = date;
    var validDate = noWeekendsOrHolidays(date);
    if(holdDays != 0 || validDate[0] == false){ //recursive call will apply OR weekend/holiday
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        if(validDate[0] == true){
            calcDate(date, holdDays - 1) //decrement holdDays and make recursive call
        }
        else{
            calcDate(date, holdDays) //recursive call (weekend/holiday)
        }
    }
    return expirationDate;
}
```